# How to append objects (not string type) to a existing file without overwriting the written data in the file in java?

Tags: java

In my java code I want to append massage objects to a file AT THE MOMENT THEY ARE BEING CREATED. When I try to append a new object it overwrites previously added data in the file. Can someone explain a method to append objects (not string type objects) one by one to a existing file without getting overwritten?

Constructor of the object:

```
public class savedEmail{

    String email;
    String subject;
    String date;
    public savedEmail(String email,String subject,String date){
        this.email = email;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.date = date;
    }
}

//The way which I tried to append the object to the file: 

class sentEmail{

    public static void save(saveEmail O) throws IOException{ObjectOutputStream op = new ObjectOutputStream(new
        FileOutputStream("saved.bin",true));

        op.write(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Help us help you - share the code you have so far.

Comment: It is not a string type object.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  This is not about appending to a text file, it’s about writing successive serialized objects to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new ObjectOutputStream, an initial sequence of bytes, or *header,* is written.  The [Java Serialization Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/specs/serialization/protocol.html#grammar-for-the-stream-format) describes it:

> stream:
>
> magic version contents

So, creating a new ObjectOutputStream each time you want to append is not an option.  You will need to open a *single* ObjectOuptutStream, and keep a reference to it.

By the way, `op.write(0)` (writing a zero) is not the same as `op.write(O)` (writing the object whose reference is in the variable whose name is the capital letter O).  This is one reason `O` is a very poor choice for a variable name.  Consider naming the method argument `email` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I figured out to solve this was, putting all the objects into an ArrayList and writing that ArrayList into a file by object serialization. If you want to add a new object to it, take the saved ArrayList back by deseriazing it, then append the new object and put the ArrayList back to the file.